# Cumulative FY to date amount per month in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need a function that will automatically sum in a column fiscal year-to-date month values.

The SQL for the query is as follows:

```
SELECT "TBD" AS CATEGORY, tbl_SP.SYSTEM, tbl_SP.T3_UNIT AS ORG, tbl_SP.T1_UNIT AS Tier1_Unit, tbl_SP.UNIT_STAFF AS Tier2_Unit, tbl_SP.T3_UNIT AS Tier3_Unit, tbl_SP.OCT_O AS OCT, tbl_SP.NOV_O AS NOV, tbl_SP.DEC_O AS [DEC], tbl_SP.JAN_O AS JAN, tbl_SP.FEB_O AS FEB, tbl_SP.MAR_O AS MAR, tbl_SP.APR_O AS APR, tbl_SP.MAY_O AS MAY, tbl_SP.JUN_O AS JUN, tbl_SP.JUL_O AS JUL, tbl_SP.AUG_O AS AUG, tbl_SP.SEP_C AS SEP, Current_M([OCT_O],[NOV_O],[DEC_O],[JAN_O],[FEB_O],[MAR_O],[APR_O],[MAY_O],[JUN_O],[JUL_O],[AUG_O],[SEP_O]) AS Current_Month_SP, AcctType([MDEP],[T3_UNIT]) AS Acct_Type
FROM tbl_SP;
```

For example, it is January so I want to SUM these columns

```
[OCT] + [NOV] + [DEC] + [JAN]
```

To test it, I tried pasting this with the alias

```
Current_YTD_value: [OCT] + [NOV] + [DEC] + [JAN]
```

It works.

So, why doesn't the following work when I use it in a function?
(I've also tried it with the type as **`'currency'`** for each month but I get a #Error!)

I have commented out other attempts, but left the relative one showing.

```
Public Function Current_M(  lJan As Long, lFeb As Long, lMar As Long, _
                            lApr As Long, lMay As Long, lJun As Long, _
                            lJul As Long, lAug As Long, lSep As Long, _
                            lOct As Long, lNov As Long, lDec As Long) As Currency

    Dim dtToday As Date

    dtToday = Now()

    Select Case Month(dtToday)
        Case 1
            Current_M = Nz(lOct, 0) + Nz(lNov, 0) + Nz(lDec, 0) + Nz(lJan, 0)
        Case 2
            Current_M = Nz(lOct, 0) + Nz(lNov, 0) + Nz(lDec, 0) + Nz(lJan, 0) + Nz(lJan, 0)

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Could you show the Query in which this function is being used, please?

Comment: Double-check the order of the fields you pass to the function when you call it in the query.  For example the query gives the function `OCT_O` as its first parameter ... `Current_M([OCT_O]`.  However the funtion's first parameter is named *lJan*.  That suggests the fields may not be mapped to the correct parameters.  But I don't think that is the cause of the error you're trying to solve now.

Comment: Thank you.  I realized that after someone edited the format of my code which originally began with Case 10 and ended with Case 9.  I imagine it was edited for visual effectiveness. But I am aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the function includes `Nz()`, here for example ...

```vb
Case 1
    Current_M = Nz(lOct, 0) + Nz(lNov, 0) + Nz(lDec, 0) + Nz(lJan, 0)
```

That may be a clue to the problem you're facing.

Since *lOct, lNov, lDec, lJan* were all declared `As Long`, they can not accept Null.  In other words, `Nz(lOct, 0)` is useless when *lOct* can never be Null.

If you call your function in the Immediate window like this ...

```vb
? Current_M(Null, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

... Access will complain with error #94, *"Invalid use of Null"*.

However, when you call the function from a query, you don't see that error message.  Instead, Access displays **#Error!** when you display the query in Datasheet View.

If you want the function to accept Null values, declare the parameters as *Variant* instead of *Long*.

That was my best guess about the cause of your problem.  However, the function would also generate an error if you're feeding it text values, such as *"NA"*, which can't be cast as long integer.

Comment: NZ is intended to retain a long value from whatever gets passed.  I didn't use variant because it is an unnecessary large footprint if I can make sure I feed the parameter the strict requirement. But I may have to try what you say because the error doesn't go away.  Then I will have to understand why NZ is not catching it in this code.